# LINQ GroupJoin() query could not be translated (method syntax)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I am new to LINQ and .NET in general and I have a problem with my query since:

> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can
> be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting
> a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

I followed the link and tried to look at issues that
seemed similar to mine, however I still couldn't resolve.

The query before the GroupJoin() works, as it returns what I expect (I've tested it)

Here is the code:

```
        var users = officeTurnsContext.Users;
        var offices = officeTurnsContext.Offices;
        var slots = officeTurnsContext.Slots;
        var userSlots = officeTurnsContext.UserSlots;

        var result = users.Where(u => u.Username == username)
            .Join(offices, u => u.OfficeId, o => o.Id, (u, o) => new { Username = u.Username, OfficeName = o.OfficeName, Capacity = o.Capacity, OfficeId = o.Id, UserId = u.Id })
            .Join(slots, uo => uo.OfficeId, s => s.OfficeId, (uo, s) =>
            new { Username = uo.Username, OfficeName = uo.OfficeName, Date = s.Date, OccupiedSeats = s.OccupiedSeats, AvailableSeats = uo.Capacity - s.OccupiedSeats, Capacity = uo.Capacity, SlotId = s.Id, UserId = uo.UserId })
            .GroupJoin(userSlots, uso => new { UserId = uso.UserId, SlotId = uso.SlotId }, us => new { UserId = us.UserId, SlotId = us.SlotId }, (uso, groupedUs) =>
            new { Username = uso.Username, OfficeName = uso.OfficeName, Date = uso.Date, OccupiedSeats = uso.OccupiedSeats, AvailableSeats = uso.AvailableSeats, Capacity = uso.Capacity, Booked = groupedUs.Count() });

        return Ok(result);
```

At one point I thought it could be the call to the Count() function, but even removing it the problem remained the same.

Comment: So did you try to call `AsEnumerable` etc? Because that's what the exception message recommends. The idea is to put it at the end of the part that translates. Another thing is that you should ask yourself why you have these joins in the first place, you should use navigation properties.

Comment: Well, GroupJoin has limitation in EF Core. Show your model first, i don’t believe you even need joins.

Comment: Instead of `GroupJoin`, use `Select` with correlated subquery returning list of related "objects". But as @Svyatoslav mentioned, most likely you can avoid all these joins with properly defined navigation properties.